# Dll e Exe com o mesmo nome = Problema?

Tags: visual-studio

Tive um problema um tanto curioso agora.

Criei um projeto(Console Application) de nome SpotifyApi no Visual Studio 2017 e logo em seguida baixei a API do Spotify no NuGet.
Quando fui rodar o código pela primeira vez o Visual Studio lançou a seguinte exceção:

> System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Não foi possível carregar o tipo SpotifyAPI.Web.SpotifyWebAPI do assembly SpotifyAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

Então comecei a procurar na Internet e descobri aqui mesmo no Stack([Ask aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623694/typeloadexception-was-unhandled-in-c-sharp)) que uma Dll e um Exe não podem conter o mesmo nome.

Quando fui verificar, a API tinha o nome **SpotifyApi.dll**. Exatamente o mesmo nome da exe (SpotifyApi.exe)

No resposta o usuário explica que o Visual Studio ja carregou uma chamada no Assembly para Spotify.exe, por isso não localiza a dll. Mas eu gostaria de entender por que uma IDE tão inteligente não sabe que são arquivos diferentes pela extensão. Por que isso ocorre? Achei um tanto curioso e gostaria de saber um pouco mais deste "problema".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há problema algum em ter os dois com o mesmo nome (desconsiderada a extensão).

São as *assemblies* que não podem ter o mesmo nome.

Os arquivos .dll e .exe não são as assemblies em si, são containers para elas. Você pode obter esses nomes por reflexão. Você também pode mudar o nome de uma *assembly* gerada por um projeto seu através da janela de propriedades do projeto no Visual Studio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O nome de cada *assembly* é uma informação importante para a plataforma .NET. Deixo a seu critério estudá-las e descobrir o porquê (e aprender várias coisas legais a mais no caminho).